# How to disable/remove the input box in wx.lib.filebrowsebutton.FileBrowseButton?

Tags: python, wxpython, filebrowse

Looks like there's no built-in option to disable/remove the `InputBox/TextCtrl` part in `wx.lib.filebrowsebutton.FileBrowseButton`, well I did come up with a workaround which is simply set `labelText` to blank and then size it down to fit only the button itself, this way visually you can tell no difference from a normal button, but I don't think it's nice enough to go with.

So is there a way to fully disable/remove the `InputBox` part? Or maybe a way to bind normal button with file browser function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need a `textctrl`, then you don't really need `wx.lib.FileBrowseButton`. You can just have a normal `wx.Button` that launches a `wx.FileDialog` instance. In fact, that's all that `wx.lib.FileBrowsBbutton` does. Here's the relevant source code, the whole thing can be viewed here: https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxPython/blob/master/wx/lib/filebrowsebutton.py

```
def OnBrowse (self, event = None):
        """ Going to browse for file... """
        current = self.GetValue()
        directory = os.path.split(current)
        if os.path.isdir( current):
            directory = current
            current = ''
        elif directory and os.path.isdir( directory[0] ):
            current = directory[1]
            directory = directory [0]
        else:
            directory = self.startDirectory
            current = ''
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, self.dialogTitle, directory, current,
                            self.fileMask, self.fileMode)

        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            self.SetValue(dlg.GetPath())
        dlg.Destroy()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate! By the way, how to make `fileMask` match both `txt` and `csv` files? I've tried with `*.{txt,csv}` but it does not work...